# Mysql: how to change SOCKET in global_variables table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out how to change socket value in global_variables table.

default value is /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

but I want to change this path to:
/mail/mysql/mysql.sock

I would really appreciate if you could suggest me how to go with this.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

It's not a dynamic value you can change while the server is on. Stop your mysql and add to your my.cnf

`socket=/mail/mysql/mysql.sock`

Or via command when you initialize the mysql server adding `--socket=/mail/mysql/mysql.sock`

References:

[MYSQL System variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_socket)

[How to Protect or Change the MySQL Unix Socket File](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-with-mysql-sock.html)